# Firebase - Detach/Unsubscribe from database : Multiple listeners at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a week with days in it.
The week has a `data-week-id` as its attribute, and each day within the week has its own `data-day-id.`

I have a function that listen in real-time for any updates within the days, for example when a task is added to one of the days. I also have a function that generates every week, removing the old one and generating a new one with new `data-week-id`'s and `data-day-id`'s. But everytime I go back to a week I already generated and add a new tasks, it render's multiple times, depending on how many times the listener was created, when the `renderTasks` function was called.

I can't seem to figure out how to unsubscribe from the previously generated week any time I go one week in the future or the past.

Here is my code:

```
function generateWeek(monday) {
    $(".week").children().remove();
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        let dayDate = moment()
            .isoWeekday(i + monday)
            .format("dddd, DD.MM");
        let dayId = moment()
            .isoWeekday(i + monday)
            .format("DD-MM-YYYY");

        const day = `
            <div class="day" data-day-id="${dayId}">
                <div class="day__head">
                    <span class="day__date">${dayDate}</span>
                    <div class="day__badges"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="day__body">
                    <div class="day__tasks-wrapper"></div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

        $(".week").append(day);
    }
    renderTasks();
}

function renderTasks() {
    let week = $(".week").attr("data-week-id");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        let day = $(this).attr("data-day-id");
        unsubscribe = db.collection(`users/${auth.currentUser.uid}/weeks/${week}/${day}`)
            .orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
                changes.forEach((change) => {
                    switch (change.type) {
                        case "added":
                            let task = `
                                <div class="${change.doc.data().completed ? "task completed" : "task"}" data-task-id="${change.doc.id}">
                                    <div class="task__text">
                                        <span>${change.doc.data().title} | ${change.doc.id}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="task__time">${change.doc.data().time}</div>
                                </div>`;
                            $(`.day[data-day-id="${day}"]`).find(".day__tasks-wrapper").prepend(task);
                            break;
                        case "removed":
                            $(`.task[data-task-id="${change.doc.id}"]`).remove();
                            break;
                        case "modified":
                            $(`.task[data-task-id="${change.doc.id}"]`).toggleClass("completed", change.doc.data().completed);
                            $(`.task[data-task-id="${change.doc.id}"]`).find(".task__text span").text(change.doc.data().title);
                            $(`.task[data-task-id="${change.doc.id}"]`).find(".task__time").text(change.doc.data().time);
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
    });
}
```

TL;DR: Help me figure out how to detach the listener created in the `renderTasks` function when a new week is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem, so here we go:

As you can see in the `renderTasks` function, I'm creating a real-time listener for every day of the week. In the firesbase documentation they say that whenever you want to unsubscribe from a listener just call the variable you named it as; this returns a function that finally let's you unsubscribe.

The thing that I was doing wrong was that I hadn't noticed that anytime the loop would run again my `unsubscribe` would get overwritten, leading to only unsubscribing from the last day of the week - Sunday.

To solve this problem I defined an empty `unsubscribeArray` that gets functions pushed into it right after the `unsubscribe` variable declaration. This way when the loop finishes we have all the unsubscribe listeners stored in the array.

```
function renderTasks(){
    // Rest of the code remains the same,
    // but I added this line after the unsubscribe variable declaration.
    unsubscribeArray.push(unsubscribe)

}
```

When we want to unsubscribe we call `unsubscribeFromPreviousWeek` - a function that loops through the `unsubscribeArray` and removes all the listeners from the previously generated week - immediately in the `generateWeek` function:

```
function generateWeek(monday) {
    unsubscribeFromPreviousWeek();
    // Rest of the code remains the same.
}
```

The `unsubscribeFromPreviousWeek` function works like this:

```
function unsubscribeFromPreviousWeek(){
    for (i = 0; i < unsubscribeArray.length; i++) {
        unsubscribeArray[i] && unsubscribeArray[i]();
    }
    unsubscribeArray = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer: attaching a listener initially returns the unsubscribe function - call that to detach the listener.

Longer answer:  I have a soon-to-be-released package, @leaddreamer/firebase-wrapper which includes a PaginatedListener creator- has a few methods to handle the detach/reattach of listeners when you page (since I'm still shaking it out, I wouldn't use it in a project until I get to version 1.1.x - but the example here is known to work):

```
 * @class
 * @static
 * @classdesc An object to allow for paginating a listener for table read from Firestore.
 * REQUIRES a sorting choice
 * masks some subscribe/unsubscribe action for paging forward/backward
 * @property {Query} Query that forms basis for the table read
 * @property {number} limit page size
 * @property {QuerySnapshot} snapshot last successful snapshot/page fetched
 * @property {PagingStatus} status status of pagination object
 *
 * @property {function} PageForward Changes the listener to the next page forward
 * @property {function} PageBack Changes the listener to the next page backward
 */
export class PaginatedListener {
  /**
   * @member {string} table
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //table = null;
  /**
   * @member {filterObject} [filterArray]
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //filterArray = null;
  /**
   * @member {sortObject} [sortArray]
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //sortArray = null;
  /**
   * @member {string} refPath
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //refPath = null;
  /**
   * @member {Query} Query
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //Query = null;
  /**
   * @member {number} limit
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //limit = PAGINATE_DEFAULT;
  /**
   * @member {QuerySnapshot} snapshot
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //snapshot = null;
  /**
   * @member {RecordListener} dataCallback
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //dataCallback = null;
  /**
   * @member {callback} errCallback
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  /**
   * @member {number} status
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   */
  //status = null; // -1 pending; 0 uninitialized; 1 updated;
  /**
   * @constructs PaginatedListener constructs an object to paginate through large
   * Firestore Tables
   * @param {!string} table a properly formatted string representing the requested collection
   * - always an ODD number of elements
   * @param {filterObject} [filterArray] an (optional) 3xn array of filter(i.e. "where") conditions
   * @param {!sortObject} [sortArray] a 2xn array of sort (i.e. "orderBy") conditions
   * @param {?refPath} refPath (optional) allows "table" parameter to reference a sub-collection
   * of an existing document reference (I use a LOT of structered collections)
   *
   * The array is assumed to be sorted in the correct order -
   * i.e. filterArray[0] is added first; filterArray[length-1] last
   * returns data as an array of objects (not dissimilar to Redux State objects)
   * with both the documentID and documentReference added as fields.
   * @param {?number} limit (optional)
   * @param {!callback} dataCallback
   * @param {!callback} errCallback
   */
  constructor(
    table,
    filterArray = null,
    sortArray,
    refPath = null,
    limit = PAGINATE_DEFAULT,
    dataCallback = null,
    errCallback = null
  ) {
    this.table = table;
    this.filterArray = filterArray;
    this.sortArray = sortArray;
    this.refPath = refPath;
    this.limit = limit;
    this._setQuery();
    this.dataCallback = dataCallback;
    this.errCallback = errCallback;
    this.status = PAGINATE_INIT;
  }

  /**
   * @private
   * @method _setQuery
   * @methodof PaginatedListener
   * @description reconstructs the underlying query
   * @returns {Query}
   */
  _setQuery() {
    const db = this.refPath ? this.refPath : fdb;
    this.Query = sortQuery(
      filterQuery(db.collection(this.table), this.filterArray),
      this.sortArray
    );
    return this.Query;
  }

  /**
   * @method PageBack
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   * @description resets the listener query to the previous page of results.
   * Unsubscribes from the current listener, constructs a new query, and sets it\
   * as the new listener
   * @returns {function} returns the unsubscriber function (for lifecycle events)
   */
  PageForward() {
    const runQuery =
      this.unsubscriber && !this.snapshot.empty
        ? this.Query.startAfter(last(this.snapshot.docs))
        : this.Query;

    //IF unsubscribe function is set, run it.
    this.unsubscriber && this.unsubscriber();

    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    this.unsubscriber = runQuery.limit(Number(this.limit)).onSnapshot(
      (QuerySnapshot) => {
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone back ebfore start)
        if (!QuerySnapshot.empty) {
          //then update document set, and execute callback
          this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        }
        this.dataCallback(RecordsFromSnapshot(this.snapshot));
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errCallback(err);
      }
    );
    return this.unsubscriber;
  }

  /**
   * @method PageBack
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   * @description resets the listener query to the next page of results.
   * Unsubscribes from the current listener, constructs a new query, and sets it\
   * as the new listener
   * @returns {function} returns the unsubscriber function (for lifecycle events)
   */
  PageBack() {
    const runQuery =
      this.unsubscriber && !this.snapshot.empty
        ? this.Query.endBefore(this.snapshot.docs[0])
        : this.Query;

    //IF unsubscribe function is set, run it.
    this.unsubscriber && this.unsubscriber();

    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    this.unsubscriber = runQuery.limitToLast(Number(this.limit)).onSnapshot(
      (QuerySnapshot) => {
        //acknowledge complete
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone back ebfore start)
        if (!QuerySnapshot.empty) {
          //then update document set, and execute callback
          this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        }
        this.dataCallback(RecordsFromSnapshot(this.snapshot));
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errCallback(err);
      }
    );
    return this.unsubscriber;
  }

  /**
   * @method ChangeLimit
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   * @description sets page size limit to new value, and restarts the paged listener
   * @param {number} newLimit
   * @returns {function} returns the unsubscriber function (for lifecycle events)
   */
  ChangeLimit(newLimit) {
    const runQuery = this.Query;

    //IF unsubscribe function is set, run it.
    this.unsubscriber && this.unsubscriber();

    this.limit = newLimit;

    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    this.unsubscriber = runQuery.limit(Number(this.limit)).onSnapshot(
      (QuerySnapshot) => {
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone back ebfore start)
        if (!QuerySnapshot.empty) {
          //then update document set, and execute callback
          this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        }
        this.dataCallback(RecordsFromSnapshot(this.snapshot));
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errCallback(err);
      }
    );
    return this.unsubscriber;
  }

  /**
   * @method ChangeFilter
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   * @description changes the filter on the subscription
   * This has to unsubscribe the current listener,
   * create a new query, then apply it as the listener
   * @param {filterObject} [filterArray] an array of filter descriptors
   * @returns {function} returns the unsubscriber function (for lifecycle events)
   */
  ChangeFilter(filterArray) {
    //IF unsubscribe function is set, run it (and clear it)
    this.unsubscriber && this.unsubscriber();

    this.filterArray = filterArray; // save the new filter array
    const runQuery = this._setQuery(); // re-build the query
    this.status = PAGINATE_PENDING;

    //fetch the first page of the new filtered query
    this.unsubscriber = runQuery.limit(Number(this.limit)).onSnapshot(
      (QuerySnapshot) => {
        this.status = PAGINATE_UPDATED;
        //*IF* documents (i.e. haven't gone back ebfore start)
        this.snapshot = QuerySnapshot;
        this.dataCallback(RecordsFromSnapshot(this.snapshot));
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errCallback(err);
      }
    );
    return this.unsubscriber;
  }

  /**
   * @method unsubscribe
   * @memberof PaginatedListener
   * @description IF unsubscribe function is set, run it.
   */
  unsubscribe() {
    //IF unsubscribe function is set, run it.
    this.unsubscriber && this.unsubscriber();
    this.unsubscriber = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I read the documentation about the ```unsubscribe()``` return function but I can't seem to make it work for what I have coded. Can you give it a shot at about how I would need to write this function to remove the listeners from all the days?

Comment: Sorry, but no, I'm not going to be able to do THAT much for you.  Why not show the MINIMUM code needed to demonstrate the issue, and maybe someone can help with that?